# Conforming an @objc enum to an @objc protocol?

Tags: swift, objective-c, enums, swift-protocols

Is it possible to conform an @objc enum to an @objc protocol?

The enum below displays an error of `Non-class type 'TestEnum' cannot conform to class protocol 'Testable'`

```
@objc protocol Testable {
    var isTesting: Bool { get }
}

// error: Non-class type 'TestEnum' cannot conform to class protocol 'Testable'
@objc enum TestEnum: Int, Testable {
    case foo

    var isTesting: Bool {
        return true
    }
}
```

Comment: Obj-C protocols can only be adopted by classes. Does `Testable` need to be an Obj-C protocol (i.e., are you actually exposing it to Obj-C), or can that be dropped?

Comment: Testable is exposed to Obj-C. It'll be some time before it's consumers are migrated to Swift to drop the @objc

Comment: Got it. In that case, unfortunately, you won't be able to directly adopt `Testable` on your `TestEnum` type. Instead, you'll have to wrap up the type in a class, which can adopt the protocol.

Answer (score 5):

[Objective-C protocols](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/WorkingwithProtocols/WorkingwithProtocols.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011210-CH11-SW3), whether defined in Obj-C with `@protocol` or in Swift with `@objc protocol`, can only be adopted by classes. This is a fact of the definition of protocols in Obj-C as a collection of methods that you expect a type to implement: only classes can be messaged in Obj-C, and only they can adopt protocols.

This [carries over to Swift](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Protocols.html#ID284):

> Note that `@objc` protocols can be adopted only by classes that inherit from Objective-C classes or other `@objc` classes. They can’t be adopted by structures or enumerations.

This means that `TestEnum` can't adopt `Testable` directly, but what you can do is wrap the enum in a class, which can adopt the protocol:

```swift
class TestEnumWrapper: Testable {
    enum TestEnum: Int {
        case foo
    }

    let value: TestEnum

    var isTesting: Bool {
        return true
    }
}
```

Whether this approach is usable in your specific situation will depend on what exactly you need to do with `TestEnum`.

Comment: Indeed, this doesn't really have anything to do with Swift, but everything to do with the Objective C object model and how enums don't play with it